# How should I send data to socket in iOS

Tags: objective-c

On the "Speak" button click(hold) I create an audio_capture queue and start the socket object. Whenever data is captured available I send it through socket. After "Speak" button release I stop audio_capture and socket.

But here few audio data gets fail to send to the socket in the following situation:

1. On "Speak" button onClick(hold) event sometime socket takes little time to start and data sent to socket delegate by audio capture fails resulting socket not started yet.
2. On the "Speak" button release I close the socket and audio_capture queue. Here socket gets close immediately and data send by audio_Capture fails by saying socket close.

So how should implement it so socket won't get closed until there is a data to be sent in an array on "Speak" button release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is:

1. When user holds the button, do not proceed anything other than initialize socket & wait for it to be finished. Once you get notified by socket delegate saying that it is ready, you can let user know that it's time to start saying something.
2. IMO, audio data should be put into a queue. Your app should not close the network socket until the queue is successfully processed.

Comment: Thanks, @RyanB.  If you have any reference or relevant example then please share. This will help a lot.

Comment: No I haven't, but it couldn't be difficult to implement this in your app.